# How to change origin of li element so that it re-sizes itself from the center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to animate the border width from 1px to 6px, but it not only moves the entire ul 6 px around but it seems like the re-sizing of the width starts from the top.

I tried to transform  the origin to the center hoping that it will make each side "grow" the same amount the same time. Any suggestions?

```
li { 
  display: inline-block;    
  border: 1px #7c7c7c solid;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 0.1s;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
}

li:hover { border: 6px #fa7722 solid; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using plain CSS Transform. You don't also need to adjust the border in the hover state. You can just use Scale on your transform property.

```
   li:hover { 
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
     transform: scale(1.5);
     border: 1px #fa7722 solid; 
   }
```

NOTE: when you transform an object it doesn't affect the position neither the layout.

Here is a live fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/ARuCOtuk/1/edit

Comment: This solution is great. The effect looks better now.

Comment: Hi @Tamás, i'm not yet aware of a method to do this. maybe it would be  good if you post it on another question. Please don't forget to mark this as answer it it solved your problem.